# R: Converting a list of lists into a data frame (Census data)

Tags: json, r, list, dataframe, census

I am trying to use the Census API to download specific tables and save them in data frames. I have been successful in downloading the data. I assemble the appropriate URL for the call and then have used the package 'rjson' to read the URL into a list. For example:

```
library(rjson)    

get <- c("B19081_002M")                                      # create vector of vars
datafile <- "http://api.census.gov/data/2009/acs5?"          # ACS 05-09
get <- paste0("get=NAME,", paste(get, collapse = ','))       # variables
geo <- "for=county:*"                                        # all counties
api_key <- "key=KEYHERE"                                     # API key
url <- paste0(datafile, paste(get, geo, api_key, sep = "&")) # creates url
data <- fromJSON(file = url)                                 # read into R

# To see an example of a problematic observation
# (this should return "Hinsdale County, Colorado")

data[[273]]
```

However, I am having difficulty converting this into a data frame. The fromJSON() function creates a list object. In most cases, the elements of the list object are chr vectors for each spatial unit (e.g. county in the above example) and the vector contains the table information and associated metadeta. In this case, I use the approach in the below working example to convert the list into a data frame where each row is a different spatial unit and each column is a different variable.

```
# Create fake data
x1 <- seq(1:5)
x2 <- rep(5,5)
l1 <- list(x1,x2)

# Convert to df
cols_per_row <- length(unlist(l1[1]))
test1 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l1), byrow = TRUE, ncol = cols_per_row))

print(test1) # success!

X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  5  5  5  5  5
```

But when I use that same approach with the list-in-list object (which arises because I am including different tables from the API), I receive an error:

```
# Create fake data
x1 <- seq(1:5)
x2 <- rep(5,5)
x3 <- list(1,2,3,4,NULL)
l2 <- list(x1,x2,x3)

# Produces an error
cols_per_row <- length(unlist(l2[1]))
test2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l2), byrow = TRUE, ncol = cols_per_row))

Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(l2), byrow = TRUE, ncol = cols_per_row) :
data length [14] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [5]
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

- I've noticed that the sub-lists are only appearing in cases where one of the variables has a NULL value.
- In the cases where the element of the main list is also a list, the sub-list is of length equal to the length of the vectors for the element of the main lists that are vectors.

**Notes**

- I do not need to use fromJSON and welcome alternatives that might make this easier.
- I do not want to use the 'acs' package to accomplish this, so please do not suggest its use. I am trying to learn how to deal with this problem.

Comment: `as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, l2))` would be a typical (though not great; you'll lose types) way. `purrr` is useful for dealing with lists; you could do something like `l2 %>% setNames(make.names(seq_along(.))) %>% at_depth(2, ~.x %||% NA) %>% map_df(unlist)`, though that may not be the most graceful version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are after:

```
simplify2array(l2)
```

EDIT:

The above solution did not work. As an alternative I would replace NULL values with NA:

```
# Function to replace NULL values to NA values inside a list
listNull2Na <- function(l) sapply(l, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x))

# Substitute NULL values in your list and get matrix:
l2 <- sapply(l2, listNull2Na)
```

Comment: I don't think it works with the real data. At least it didn't in my test (resulted in a weird shape -- cut off one dimension and gave 3,222 columns). Correct me if I'm wrong though, OP.

Comment: @Hack-R sadly I don't have real data, so cannot test. I am working on the toy data that OP provided...

@user3614648 this function is used internally by `sapply()` not much info about it. But we can inspect it's code by typing `simplify2array` - it does somewhat similar thing to what you were doing - unlists the data and then arranges it into a suitable array. Works in your case because each sublist has the same length. See: `lengths(l2)` (even with NULL). Might not work if the lengths were different.

Comment: @user3614648 I see. Maybe you can elaborate on what is incorrect or add a simple case where this does not work for you?

Comment: Upon reflection this is not quite correct. I developed a hackish way of getting a data frame that I wanted where each column is a vector (not a list). To put it into a "tidy" data frame, I first used: as.data.frame(t(simplify2array(data))), transposing from NxK to KxN. I realized each column in the data frame was a list, which was not what I wanted. So, I converted everything to character type via:  as.data.frame(sapply(as.data.frame(t(simplify2array(data)), stringsAsFactors =  FALSE),as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE). This is terribly done and I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Thank you for elaboration. The problem is that simplify2array (and do.call(cbind, l2)) leaves columns in the class of a "list". So you end up with a data.frame of lists in the end. Thinking about a simple solution...

Comment: Edited the answer. Not as nice as it was before but seems to be working?

Answer (score 2):

I give thee a hack using the real query:

```
tmp <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=4))

for(i in 1:length(data)){
  if(length(t(unlist(data[i]))) == 4){
  tmp[i,] <- t(unlist(data[i]))
  } else{
    cat("Row number ", i, "has an abnormal length \n")
  }
}
```

> ```
> Row number  273 has an abnormal length 
> Row number  550 has an abnormal length 
> Row number  1900 has an abnormal length 
> Row number  2733 has an abnormal length 
> Row number  2737 has an abnormal length 
> Row number  2753 has an abnormal length
> ```

```
head(tmp)
```

> ```
> 1                               NAME B19081_002M state county
> 2     Aleutians East Borough, Alaska        8469    02    013
> 3 Aleutians West Census Area, Alaska        7691    02    016
> 4     Anchorage Municipality, Alaska         920    02    020
> 5         Bethel Census Area, Alaska        2414    02    050
> 6        Bristol Bay Borough, Alaska        9635    02    060
> ```

Only 6 out of > 3,000 had an abnormal length, but if you want rescue those rows it's possible to do so by adding another line to fill in the missing value with a placeholder.

Finally, don't forget that the first row is a header, so you can write it to the `colnames` of your data.frame.

Comment: This is a useful hack to identify the problematic elements of the list. It is not an answer to the problem per se, but I'll upvote since it is helpful.

Note: it is also somewhat puzzling why the variable names are appearing in the first row (in my own application I have automated a fix for this) when the object is returned.